# How to reassign values in a series that match a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series with various names which need to be renamed. The values which need to be changed are contained within a list.

```py
change_list = ['b', 'c']
new_name = 'x'

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'sp': 'a'},
    {'sp': 'b'},
    {'sp': 'c'},
    {'sp': 'b'},
    {'sp': 'c'}])

df[df['sp'].isin(change_list)]['sp'] = new_name
```

The result should be the dataframe with the new_name assigned to each 'sp' value that matches the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.loc` (without `['sp']` at the end):

```
df.loc[df['sp'].isin(change_list)] = new_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `['sp']` :)

```
change_list = ['b', 'c']
new_name = 'x'

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'sp': 'a'},
    {'sp': 'b'},
    {'sp': 'c'},
    {'sp': 'b'},
    {'sp': 'c'}])

df[df['sp'].isin(change_list)] = new_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change_list = ['b', 'c']
new_name = 'x'

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'sp': 'a'},
    {'sp': 'b'},
    {'sp': 'c'},
    {'sp': 'b'},
    {'sp': 'c'}])

df.loc[df.sp.isin(change_list), :] = new_name
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but can you explain why it does, and describe how it fixes OP's problem? This post is currently in the Low Quality Posts queue, but should probably be kept with some more explanatory text.